# Templatedoesnotexist error in django where the template is there

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am getting Templatedoesnotexist error when i command 'run server'.

I want my home.html to run when the url is '/'.

and my template (home.html) is in templates directory but it says it cannot find the template.

My views are fine, I used TemplateView for home page and connected it in urls.py.

What should I do..?

Comment: Is your app added to INSTALLED_APPS in settings?

Comment: @devdob yes  ...

Comment: Tell us more about your project structure and settings file please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the template directory and sure your views are fine. The problem could come from your setting.
Although it is hard to understand from where the issue come as you did not provided view of your code but try this
In your **settings.py** you have to tell django you have added your templates directory

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['your_app_name/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]